# React hook: how to update component at certain time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a model that has `expiredAt` property:

```js
type Expirable {
   expiredAt: Date;
}
```

The component (idea) is basically like the following:

```js
const [model, setModel] = useState<Expirable>({
  expiredAt: new Date((new Date).getTime() + 20000)
});

return (
  { expired(model) ? (
     <Text>Expired</Text>
  ) : (
     <Text>Not Expired</Text>
  )}
);
```

How can I implement `expired` function (or React Hook) to update component at due time?

Please notice that multiple components are rendered with models fetched from API, so hard-coding won't be a solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to define a custom hook (to simplify your component code and future reuse):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const useExpired = (time)=>{
  const [expired, setExpired] = useState(false);
  const timoutRef = useRef();
  useEffect(()=>{
    timoutRef.current = setTimeout(()=>{
      setExpired(true);
    }, time);
    return ()=>{
      clearTimeout(timoutRef.current);
    }
  },[time]);
  return expired;
}

export default function App() {
  const [model, setModel] = useState({
    expiredAt: new Date().getTime() + 5000,
  });

  const expired = useExpired(model.expiredAt - new Date().getTime());

  return <div>{expired ? <h1>Expired</h1> : <h1>Not expired</h1>}</div>;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to store the time out ref using useRef. Just use `const timoutRef = setTimeout(...` inside your useEffect

Answer (score 2):

Live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-62704463-6gd3b)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [model, setModel] = useState({
    expiredAt: new Date().getTime() + 5000,
    expired: false
  });

  const expired = m => {
    return m.expired === true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setModel(currentModel => ({ ...currentModel, expired: true }));
    }, model.expiredAt - new Date().getTime());
  }, []);

  return <div>{expired(model) ? <h1>Expired</h1> : <h1>Not expired</h1>}</div>;
}
```

Comment: You are not using useEffect correctly. Send an empty array to second parameter.

Comment: @bravemaster thanks for bring that up, updated. No idea why every time when I add the empty array, eslint gives me a warning. Same on codesandbox.

Comment: Use `// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. Since setTimeout function needs to be called just once, we don't need model dependency. For more info, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks! (Updated in codesandbox)

Comment: directly access `model` in `setTimeout` might cause `model` is not updated problem: Check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Comment: @TonyNguyen Thanks for the heads up! I've approved your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can add expired property for model and set set it to true when the time coms

```
const [model, setModel] = useState<Expirable>({
  expiredAt: new Date((new Date).getTime() + 20000)
  expired: false
});
// You can also use useRef instead of useState here.
const [expirationTimeoutId] = useState(() =>{
  return setTimeout(() =>{
     // setModel on currentModel to have last value of model
     setModel(currentModel => ({...currentModel, expired: true }))
  }, model.expiredAt - Date.now())
});
// You should clear timeout when the component is unmounted
useEffect(() =>{
   return () => clearTimeout(expirationTimeoutId)
},[])

return (
  { model.expired ? (
     <Text>Expired</Text>
  ) : (
     <Text>Not Expired</Text>
  )}
);
```

Updated: If you don't want to touch model you can do this

```
const [model, setModel] = useState<Expirable>({
  expiredAt: new Date((new Date).getTime() + 20000)
});

const [isModelExpired, setIsModelExpired] = useState(false)

const [expirationTimeoutId] = useState(() =>{
  return setTimeout(() =>{
    setIsModelExpired(true)
  }, model.expiredAt - Date.now())
});
// You should clear timeout when the component is unmounted
useEffect(() =>{
   return () => clearTimeout(expirationTimeoutId)
},[])

return (
  { isModelExpired ? (
     <Text>Expired</Text>
  ) : (
     <Text>Not Expired</Text>
  )}
);
```

Comment: Is there any way that you don't need to touch model attribute?

Comment: Yes @bravemaster you can separate the `expired` to a new state. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apart you said

> Please notice that multiple components are rendered with models fetched from API, so hard-coding won't be a solution here.

but in your example you used an hard-coded expiration time rather than showing us how the model is provided to the component once fetched from API; I'll assume the model is provided to the component as a prop.

Once said that, the purpose of React Hooks is to make the code shorter (better maintainable) but this is true only when the component has to do a really few things. This is a classical example case where using a class component makes the code much more short, clean and maintainable.

```
class ModelComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const elapsed = props.model.expiredAt - new Date().getTime();

    this.state = { expired: elapsed <= 0 };
    if(! this.state.expired) // Set the timeout only if the model isn't already expired
      this.state.to = setTimeout(() => this.setState({ expired: true, to: null }), elapsed);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if(this.state.to) clearTimeout(this.state.to);
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.expired ? (
      <Text>Expired</Text>
    ) : (
      <Text>Not Expired</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Is this code more clear or more complicated than the possible solutions using React Hooks?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Models are fetched from API, `expiredAt` too for that matter. I just wanted to show an example there.

Comment: My codebase is entirely React hooks. Is there any way I can combine React hooks with react component, if I'd want to use your answer? Or is mixing React Hooks with React class components even a good approach?

Comment: There is absolutely no problem mixing them; I usually write main components as class components (since they are more powerful) and small satellite components as function components... using hooks when required.